# error: failed to select a version for `syn`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-tokio, nearprotocol, rust-diesel

```
error: failed to select a version for `syn`. \
    ... required by package `serde_derive v1.0.125`\
    ... which satisfies dependency `serde_derive = "=1.0.125"` of package `serde v1.0.125`    
    ... which satisfies dependency `serde = "^1.0.125"` of package `mongodb v2.1.0`\
    ... which satisfies dependency `mongodb = "^2.1"` of package `wagmeet v0.1.0 
 \(/mnt/e/College/Eighth Semester/Crypto_Capable/wagmeet_app)`\
versions that meet the requirements `^1.0.60` are: 1.0.86, 1.0.85, 1.0.84, 1.0.83, 1.0.82, 1.0.81, 1.0.80, 1.0.79, 1.0.78, 1.0.77, 1.0.76, 1.0.75, 1.0.74, 1.0.73, 1.0.72, 1.0.71, 1.0.70, 1.0.69, 1.0.68, 1.0.67, 1.0.66, 1.0.65, 1.0.64, 1.0.63, 1.0.62, 1.0.61, 1.0.60

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `syn v1.0.57`\
    ... which satisfies dependency `syn = "=1.0.57"` 
    \ of package `near-sdk-core v3.0.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `near-sdk-core = "=3.0.1"` of package `near-sdk-macros v3.0.1` \
    ... which satisfies dependency `near-sdk-macros = "=3.0.1"` \ of package `near-sdk v3.0.1`   
    ... which satisfies dependency `near-sdk = "^3"` of package `wagmeet v0.1.0 `\

failed to select a version for `syn` which could resolve this conflict
```

Cargo.toml file

```
[package]
name = "wagmeet"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["rlib","cdylib"]

[dependencies]
near-sdk = "^3.1.0"
near-contract-standards = "^3.1.1"
mongodb = "2.0.0"
bson = { version = "2", features = ["chrono-0_4"] } # Needed for using chrono datetime in doc
tokio = "1"
chrono = "0.4" # Used for setting DateTimes
serde = "1"
serde_derive = "1.0.135"
```

- Update
  added the cargo.toml file

I have tried various versions nothing seems to be working for now. Is  mongoDb even compatible with Near protocol?

Comment: Please share your `Cargo.toml` (or at least the `dependencies` section), otherwise it'd be impossible to help.

Comment: Added the file. Sorry for not adding it earlier

Answer (score 5):

There is a conflict between two of your dependencies: `near-sdk` requires *exactly* `syn` version `1.0.57`, and `mongodb` requires *at least* `syn` version `1.0.60`. Clearly both cannot exist together.

You have few solutions:

- Patch `near-sdk` to support later `syn` versions. This is usually not recommended.
- Upgrade `near-sdk` to the pre-release `4.0.0` ([currently 4.0.0-pre.7](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/4.0.0-pre.7/near_sdk/index.html)) that supports later `syn` versions. This is an unstable version, and may break.
- Downgrade `mongodb` to a version that supports `syn` version `1.0.57`. The latest version that supports that is 1.2.5, so you need to specify in your Cargo.toml `mongodb = "=1.2.5"`. But this relies on an old, unsupported version.

There is no "best solution". All solutions are bad. I would probably upgrade `near-sdk` to 4.0.0, but what to do depends on your needs.

Comment: if solutions #2 and #3 doesn't work try to backup and erase your Cargo.lock and compile again

Answer (score 0):

This can be the case when you're using workspaces and multipe toml files that point to different versions of a dependency. When you're using the dependency in your bin project they collide and dump that error on you.

Make sure all dependencies point to the same lib version and run `cargo update`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I added a git dependency. Running

```
cargo update
```

fixed the problem.

More info:

The error I got was:

```
all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `bytemuck v1.13.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `bytemuck = "^1.7"` (locked to 1.13.1) of package `eframe v0.23.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `eframe = "^0.23.0"` (locked to 0.23.0) of package `myproject v1.4.0 

failed to select a version for `bytemuck` which could resolve this conflict
```

and then cargo update resulted in:

```
Updating crates.io index
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/huggingface/candle.git`
    Updating ab_glyph v0.2.21 -> v0.2.23
    Updating accesskit v0.11.0 -> v0.11.2
    Updating accesskit_consumer v0.15.0 -> v0.15.2
    Updating accesskit_macos v0.7.1 -> v0.9.0
    Updating accesskit_unix v0.5.0 -> v0.5.2
    Updating accesskit_windows v0.14.0 -> v0.14.3
    Updating accesskit_winit v0.14.1 -> v0.14.4
      Adding addr2line v0.21.0
    ... and a whole lot more of Updating, Adding, and Removing.
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following methods...

- check your patched dependencies are pointed to the correct source repository
- if you use other project's Cargo.lock or change some dependencies as you go, remove target folder and build again
- check compilation logs for incorrect dependency paths!
- update your Rust
- delete .cargo and .rustup directories